# Count occurrences in a specific time window Python

Tags: python, datetime

My data contained the time when the field force visited a client. What I need to do, is to compute for each day and for each client the occurrences of the visits (in between specific time ranges - for example, every 15minutes from 8am to 8pm.) Ideally, to draw the distribution of an histogram with the time interval on the x-axis and the occurrences on the y-axis.

This how my current data frame looks like:

| Client | Hour | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11:14:48 | Monday |
| A | 11:24:34 | Monday |
| B | 15:34:34 | Tuesday |
| B | 13:34:35 | Tuesday |
| B | 15:10:22 | Tuesday |
| B | 15:01:02 | Tuesday |
| ... | ... | ... |

The output should be something like this, than I can use to plot an histogram:

| Interval | Client | Occurrences | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00:00 - 8:15:00 | A | 0 | Monday |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 11:00:00 - 11:15:00 | A | 1 | Monday |
| 11:15:00 - 11:30:00 | A | 1 | Monday |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly hacky, but should work. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know. This would be way easier if you had actual date-times instead of a mix between a time interval and day names.

Here is the data I am using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Client':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Hour': ['11:14:48', '11:24:34', '15:34:34', '13:34:35', '15:10:22', '15:01:02'],
                   'Day':['Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday']})
```

Here the code:

```
TIME_START = '08:00:00'
TIME_END = '20:00:00'
INTERVAL = '15min'

def reindex_by_date(df):
    df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime('1970-1-1 ' + df['Hour'].astype(str))
    dt_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start=f'1970-1-1 {TIME_START}', end=f'1970-1-1 {TIME_END}', freq=INTERVAL))
    resampled_df = df.resample('15min', on='Hour').count().reindex(dt_index).fillna(0).rename(columns={'Hour':'Occurrences'}).rename_axis('Hour').reset_index()
    resampled_df['Client'] = df['Client'].iat[0]
    resampled_df['Day'] = df['Day'].iat[0]
    resampled_df['Hour'] = resampled_df['Hour'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') + ' - ' + (resampled_df['Hour'] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    return resampled_df.rename(columns={'Hour':'Interval'})

result = df.groupby(['Client', 'Day'], as_index=False).apply(reindex_by_date).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

`result` looks like this:

```
               Interval Client  Occurrences      Day
0   08:00:00 - 08:15:00      A          0.0   Monday
1   08:15:00 - 08:30:00      A          0.0   Monday
2   08:30:00 - 08:45:00      A          0.0   Monday
3   08:45:00 - 09:00:00      A          0.0   Monday
4   09:00:00 - 09:15:00      A          0.0   Monday
..                  ...    ...          ...      ...
44  19:00:00 - 19:15:00      B          0.0  Tuesday
45  19:15:00 - 19:30:00      B          0.0  Tuesday
46  19:30:00 - 19:45:00      B          0.0  Tuesday
47  19:45:00 - 20:00:00      B          0.0  Tuesday
48  20:00:00 - 20:15:00      B          0.0  Tuesday

[98 rows x 4 columns]
```

While the nonzero entries are:

```
               Interval Client  Occurrences      Day
12  11:00:00 - 11:15:00      A          1.0   Monday
13  11:15:00 - 11:30:00      A          1.0   Monday
22  13:30:00 - 13:45:00      B          1.0  Tuesday
28  15:00:00 - 15:15:00      B          2.0  Tuesday
30  15:30:00 - 15:45:00      B          1.0  Tuesday
```

Comment: Hey user2246849, thanks for your fast reply. I'll try your code out and keep you posted. Regarding the data-times, I do have them in full format, but I thought would be easier to separate these. Let me know if you have any recommendation then.

Comment: Hey, I got this error and I don't understand why: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.time") to str.
Do you have any clues?

Comment: Probably your df['Hour'] is a column of datetime.time objects, which makes total sense! I edited the answer (first line of the reindex_by_date function). Let me know if it works!

Comment: Great it works! Thanks a lot for your help. By any chance, do you know how to do histogram with these and group them by client and day?